# get Get property from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one method for push class property into NameValuCollection

```
private NameValueCollection ObjectToCollection(object objects)
{

    NameValueCollection parameter = new NameValueCollection();


    Type type = objects.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                    BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(objects, null) == null)
        {
            parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), "");
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString() != "removeProp")
            {
                parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return parameter;
    }
```

in my case when I pass My Model class to this method it's for correctly,but when in my Model class I use another Model like this

```
public class Brand
{
    public MetaTags MetaTag { get; set; } // <---- Problem is here

    public string BrandName { get; set; }

}

public class MetaTags
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

it's not add MetaTags Class Property to the collection and just Add MetaTag to the collection

I want this method return this OutPut

```
key:Title       Value:value
key:Description Value:value
key:Language    Value:value
key:BrandName   Value:value
```

but this method return this

```
key:MetaTag     Value:
key:BrandName   Value:value
```

how i can do it ?
very thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding a empty string, check whether the current property is `MetaTags` or not. If so, use this function recursively.

```
private NameValueCollection ObjectToCollection(object objects)
{

NameValueCollection parameter = new NameValueCollection();


Type type = objects.GetType();

PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(MetaTags))
    {
            parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(),ObjectToCollection(property.GetValue(objects, null)))
    }
    else{
    if (property.GetValue(objects, null) == null)
    {
        parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), "");
    }
    else
    {
        if (property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString() != "removeProp")
        {
            parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString());
        }
    }
    }
}

return parameter;
}
```

Comment: The code is specific for `MetaTags`. You can make it generic too.

Comment: ,thank for your help, but i use this method ,in many place ,i want it's work for any class,not just for MetaTag,,how i can do it ?

Comment: you can check `property.GetValue(objects, null).GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                BindingFlags.Public).Length`
in that case.

Comment: But it might cause a performance hit, not sure about that though.